# i am unable to open the application when tapped on the deep links using flutter only android 13

Tags: flutter, firebase, android-deep-link

I encountered an issue where I couldn't access the application initially through the deep link provided. However, when I closed the link and directly launched the application, I was able to navigate to the correct screen. Nevertheless, when attempting to interact with the application by tapping on certain elements, it didn't respond or open as expected.

```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="Example.page.link"
                android:scheme="https" />
            <data
                android:host="www.Example.com"
                android:scheme="https" />
            <data
                android:host="www.Example.com"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="Example.page.link"
                android:scheme="http" />

            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:host="Example.page.link" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"/>
        </intent-filter>
```